# Do I need a VkFramebuffer for each VkImageView?

Tags: vulkan, framebuffer

I am following this tutorial to learn Vulkan: https://vulkan-tutorial.com .

I am at the Framebuffers section: https://vulkan-tutorial.com/en/Drawing_a_triangle/Drawing/Framebuffers.

It appears as if the author is binding a different VkFramebuffer per VkImageView previously created. He had created 3 VkImageViews so now he created 3 VkFramebuffers. Is this necessary?

The tutorials says this:

> You can only use a framebuffer with the render passes that it is compatible with, which roughly means that they use the same number and type of attachments.

Does this mean I can create one VkFramebuffer which contains all created VkImageViews instead as long as I specify that in the renderpass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are confused as to what the code is doing.

To render to a `VkFramebuffer` means to starting a render pass using that framebuffer to provide the attachments for the render pass. *All* the attachments. If you have a framebuffer with 3 attachments, that means you have a render pass that has 3 attachments, and that you're rendering to all of them (during the render pass; individual subpass render to a subset of the attachments).

But that's not what this code is doing. This code wants to render to different images *at different times*. So on one frame, it renders to one image, on the next frame, it renders to a different image, and so on.

To do that, you need different `VkFramebuffer` objects.

Comment: To add to this: it is often the case that you use the same set of images for the attachments for each frame, except for the swapchain. Thus, if you have an N-buffer swapchain (usually, 2 or 3), then you'll need N VkFramebuffers, because each FB will point to an unique swapchain surface. If the swapchain didn't use different images, then you could use the same VkFramebuffer.